# "→" in string is causing error "Illegal XML character 001A was found in an SQL/XML expression" (DB2)

Tags: sql, xml, db2, character

I need to merge multiple rows from my database and to do it I need to get rid of some specific characters. I use following code:

```
  REPLACE(
        (CAST(XMLSERIALIZE(XMLAGG(XMLTEXT(
              CONCAT(RTNTXT.LIN_TX,'')
                                         )
                                 ) AS CLOB(10024)
                          ) AS VARCHAR(402)
             )
        ),'&#x0d;',''
        )  AS NARRATIVE
```

Once in any of `<mystring>` records I have sign →, my query shows warning about illegal XML character 001A.

I tried to use some google advice and transform code to:

```
  REPLACE(
        (CAST(XMLSERIALIZE(XMLAGG(XMLTEXT(
              CONCAT(RTNTXT.LIN_TX,'')
                                         )
                                 ) AS CLOB(10024)
                          ) AS VARCHAR(402)
             )
        ),x'1A',''
        )  AS NARRATIVE
```

but the error remains.

Can you tell me what I can amend in syntax to make it work?

Comment: What is the exact Db2-column-datatype of column RTNTXT.LIN_TX ?

Comment: What is the DB codepage and platform? What is the logic you try to apply?

Answer (score 0):

You must remove illegal XML characters from a string **before** you pass it to XML functions.
Consider the following example. If you uncomment the commented out string, you get SQLCODE=-20377 with similar text you mentioned. Note, that there is no problem with the '→' character. The problem is with the x'1A' one.

```
WITH MYTAB (LIN_TX) AS 
(
VALUES 
  'abc→abc'
, 'xyz' || x'1a' || 'xyz'
)
SELECT
  XMLSERIALIZE (XMLAGG (XMLTEXT (REGEXP_REPLACE (LIN_TX, '\x1A', ''))) AS VARCHAR (402)) AS CORRECT
--, XMLSERIALIZE (XMLAGG (XMLTEXT (LIN_TX)) AS VARCHAR (402)) AS INCORRECT
FROM MYTAB
```